# Commit message with only min insync replicas?

Tags: apache-kafka

When I config the acknowledge to all `ACKs=all` in my Kafka Producer, and the `min.insync.replicas`=2 with `replicas.factor`=3, and there is only 2 brokers in the in sync list isr=2-3 (consider that the broker 4 has failed), is the message going to be committed ?

Answer (score 3):

acks=all means - wait for ack from all available in-sync-replicas.

min.insync.replicas=2 means - when acks=all make sure you have at least 2.

so, the answer is YES, it will be committed, event if the third replica is down.

Comment: As a small correction: 'acks=all' means wait for ack from all in-sync-replicas. (An available replica can be out-of-sync and Kafka doesn't wait it until this replica catch up the leader and became an in-sync-replica again)